# Where is my DNS configured on my upgraded Ubuntu server?

Tags: networking, server, dns

I have an Ubuntu VM that was installed with Ubuntu 16.04. It was functioning normally with network access and was able to resolve DNS.

I then upgraded it, via `do-release-upgrade` to Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 20.04 and then Ubuntu 22.04. Between each upgrade there was a reboot. I therefore must assume that DNS was working as of the 20.04 upgrade since it was able to download and process package updates.

Now, with 22.04, I am getting `SERVFAIL` errors when attempting lookups via `nslookup`.

```
$ nslookup google.com
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find google.com: SERVFAIL
```

The error refers to the DNS server 127.0.0.53 which I understand to be a loopback address. However, I cannot find where to change this.

Most sites say that I should be looking in the netplan.yaml configuration, but the netplan folder is empty:

```
/etc/netplan$ ls -la
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Sep  7  2021 .
drwxr-xr-x 116 root root 12288 Nov 25 13:32 ..
```

I have tried to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and changing the `dns-nameservers` line:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.100.99.xxx
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.100.99.yyy
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

After this change, I've restarted the `networking` service and rebooted - no change.

I know that I can edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` - which currently reflects the 127.0.0.53 address, and I am able to get DNS services to work instantly. This change does not survive a reboot.

`systemctl status network-manager` reveals `network-manager.service could not be found`.

Where do I change my DNS settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using nmcli, for example: `nmcli device mod $deviceName ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"`. `nmcli device` to list defined devices.

To check DNS: `nmcli device show  | grep IP4.DNS`

EDIT: The systemd-resolved service overwrites `/etc/resolv.conf`. If it is running you can set DNS in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and restart the service with `systemctl restart systemd-resolved`.

Comment: ```$  nmcli device show  | grep IP4.DNS
Command 'nmcli' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install network-manager  # version 1.2.2-29, or
sudo apt  install network-manager  # version 1.36.6-0ubuntu2
See 'snap info network-manager' for additional versions.```

Comment: My question, I suppose, is that if ```nmcli``` is not currently installed, is there something else managing the DNS?

Comment: Sorry, I thought nmcli was installed by default. Is the systemd-resolved service running? Try `systemctl status systemd-resolved`. This is what overwrites `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: If this service is running then I think you can set your DNS in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and restart the service with `systemctl restart systemd-resolved`.